# Error:Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils' Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Good day I was working on an application in the Android Studio but when I returned to open the program after restarting the PC I launched this error:

> Error:Unable to load class 'org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Pressing Re-download keeps marking the same error and pressing stop gradle only closes, I leave screenshot.

First of all, Thanks.

Comment: share your app level build.gradle file please

Comment: @Kushan I solved it by reinstall a newer Android 3.0 version. Thank you